# UI Bootstrap directive's scope is not updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using AngularJs in my project, and I would like to get a dialog where the user will type in a string, to get this string later on the page in the foreground. I decided to use the modal directive from UI Bootstrap, and I edited the on-line plunker to make some test; so, within this link (http://plnkr.co/edit/Nu5J5NbAYrx9UGQtBSOh) there is my project. The trouble comes on the file example.js, row 34: how come that the model of the input text ("username") is not defined on its controller? What is the problem? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Not sure why it was voted to be close but to me it looks like a valid question (and has a valid response from @Ryan Q already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you have a scope hierarchy issue [Check out Scopes for a description](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

To fix this you should make it a best practice to put primitive values on a scope object model.

Old Way

```
$scope.username = "";
```

Better Way

```
$scope.model = {
    username: ""
  }

//and of course change your html to be ng-model="model.username"
```

In some cases not using an object is fine, but due to how Angular-ui set up modals there are several scopes in play to deal with.

[Here is the example updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Ku3FoIjq7nunGmEkHs6?p=preview)